# Is good practice casting inside comparator?

Tags: java, comparator

I have next classes

```
class Person {  private String name; }

class Student extends Person {  private int studyPlace;  private int studyYears; }

class Worker extends Person {  private String workPosition;  private int experienceYears; }
```

I want to storage objects all these classes inside one collection `List<Person> persons.`

For sorting I want to use next class

```
class DurationComparator implements Comparator<Person> {

    @Override
    public int compare(Person o1, Person o2) {
        if (o1 == null && o2 == null) {
            return 0;
        }
        if (o1 == null) {
            return 1;
        }
        if (o2 == null) {
            return -1;
        }

        int p1 = 0;
        int p2 = 0;

        if (o1 instanceOf Student){
            p1 = ((Student) o1).getStudyYears();
        }


        if (o1 instanceOf Worker){
            p1 = ((Worker) o1).getExperienceYears();
        }


        if (o2 instanceOf Student){
            p2 = ((Student) o2).getStudyYears();
        }


        if (o2 instanceOf Worker){
            p2 = ((Worker) o2).getExperienceYears();
        }

        return p2 - p1;

    }
}
```

I know about LSP principe. Is it good practise to cast SubClass type to Base type?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't look good to me.  Your 'Person' comparator has to know about all possible subclasses.  When you later add 'Manager extends Person', you have to fix the comparator, or else all Managers are the same.  And if there's some other Person that doesn't have some sort of 'years' value, it is unclear how you'd compare it.

One better approach would be for Person to have an abstract method that returned the number to be used for comparison.

```
 class Person {
    …
    int getYears();
    …
 }
```

then the body of the comparator is (ignoring the null considerations) just

```
 return o2.getYears() - o1.getYears();
```

This is intrusive on Person, in that firstly it adds a method to Person you did not previously have, and secondly it forces each Person subclass to expose a suitable 'years' value.  On the other hand, if you don't do something like that, then the idea of being able to compare arbitrary Persons is not well-founded.

Comment: You're right. My solution also violated OCP principe of SOLID. Thank you

Comment: And then, use [`Comparator.comparingInt(Person::getYears)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Comparator.html#comparingInt(java.util.function.ToIntFunction)) to get rid of the redundancy and all the syntactic noise.